# Errors while converting .Net Core Web project from VS 2015 to VS 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, coreclr

I have `ASP.NET Core` web project that is developed using VS 2015 Community. The project is using project.json file. The web site is been in production for last few months. Now i have downloaded VS 2017 Community.  VS 2017 auto converted the project and but got so many errors on compilation which i could not resolved.

So i created brand new .netcore web project in VS 2017, installed all the dependencies that old project(VS 2015) had ( except the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` because now it is auto referenced)

Then copied all the C#, js, css, images etc files from old project to new project.

Here are the NugetPackages project is referencing to. The version of the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` is `1.1.2`

[image]

Now when i compile new project in VS 2017 i get below errors

> Error CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e,
>   Retargetable=Yes'.

Do i have to reference `mscorlib` directly? How? Which package has this assembly?

> Error CS0012  The type 'HttpStatusCode' is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e,
>   Retargetable=Yes'.

Where is `System.Net` assembly?

> Error CS0433  The type 'HttpResponseMessage' exists in both
>   'System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Net.Http,
>   Version=4.1.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>
> Error CS0433  The type 'HttpClient' exists in both 'System.Net.Http,
>   Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and
>   'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>
> Error CS0433  The type 'HttpClient' exists in both 'System.Net.Http,
>   Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and
>   'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

How do i find which package has different versions of `System.Net.Http` installed?

How do i resolve these issues.

Comment: First, try out cli migration (`dotnet migrate`) in the solution folder, it should convert all projects within it. I had better experience during the VS 2017 RC with it than with VS2017 project conversion. Second check in the converted csproj if the correct NetCore.App verison is referenced (`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>` and `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.2</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>`. The other messages there seem to imply that you have one wrong package which downloads a diferent version of ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core and its dependencies, check dependency graph by unfolding it

Comment: Can't help you with your migration issues, because you gave no info on the matter, but I managed to fix mine.
Anyway, the issues you are facing in your new project don't mean much. You have to look over your csproj file to fix those errors. Did you run dotnet restore?

Comment: well i fixed my issue by creating one more brand new core web project, then copy all the files and then add dependencies until i dont see any error. versioning is always been annoying part in .net